# Was it permissible for me to drink water and breaking my fast after i accidentally swallowed soap?

Tags: fiqh, ramadan, sawm

I some how managed to swallow some soap while I was fasting.I was worried for my health due to other health conditions, and every article I read about accidentally swallowing soap, said to drink plenty of water, then I'd be fine. Due too my anxiety and fear of my other medical condition increasing, I drank water therefore breaking my fast.

**Question:** Was it permissible for me to drink water and breaking my fast after i accidentally swallowed soap?

Comment: Do you follow a particular madhab? Most scholars might even say that when you swallowed the soap (even though it was a mistake), your fast would be broken, therefore drinking water or not wouldn't matter.

Comment: How did you swallow the soap?

Answer (score -2):

Your intention is verily important. What was your intention while drinking water? Did you say that it was already broken so I can drink and eat?

> Al-Bukhaari (6669) and Muslim (1155) narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may
>   ALLAH(s.w.t.) be pleased with him) said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of
>   ALLAH(s.w.t.) be upon him) said: “Whoever forgets he is fasting and eats or
>   drinks, let him complete his fast for it is ALLAH(s.w.t.) Who has fed him and
>   given him to drink.”

We can infer from your circumstance that you was still fast even though forgetfully swallow soap until drinking water. So, your intention is major factor. What did you think before/during drinking water? However, if you have a problem related to your health, you aren't forced to be fast. By doing this, you are tyrannising yourself. ALLAH(s.w.t.) doesn't love oppressors.
***Consequently, ask yourself and your  conscience because it says best fatwaa about your case.***

Comment: "forgets" and "accidentally" are according to the scholars different things. And he didn't say he forgetfully swallowed the soap. So maybe you should add some scholarly references..

Comment: My reference is adequate don't worry. @Kilise

Comment: See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40820/15201) question, maybe then you'd understand that you need stronger references

Comment: do not worry inshaALLAH