# Which scholars say that your fast is valid even if you eat or drink by mistake under Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, islamic-scholar

I know that most scholars generally agree that if a person **forgets** that he is fasting, and he then eats,drinks or has intercourse, his fast is still valid due to the hadith:

> مَنْ **نَسِيَ** وَهُوَ صَائِمٌ فَأَكَلَ أَوْ شَرِبَ فَلْيُتِمَّ صَوْمَهُ فَإِنَّمَا أَطْعَمَهُ اللَّهُ وَسَقَاهُ ‏
>
> If anyone **forgets** that he is fasting and eats or drinks he should complete his fast, for it is only Allah Who has fed him and given him drink.
>
> [Sahih Muslim -  The Book of Fasting](https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/222)

With exception in the Maliki madhab, which say you have to do qadaa even though you forgot (they basically argue this hadith isn't valid in Ramadan).

---

Now, In an translated answer in IslamQA, [(en)](https://islamqa.info/en/50041), [(ar)](https://islamqa.info/ar/50041), it seems they translate the word "nasiyan" to "by mistake":

> > روى اِبْن خُزَيْمَةَ (1999) عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَة أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال
> > مَنْ أَفْطَرَ فِي شَهْر رَمَضَان **نَاسِيًا** فَلَا قَضَاء عَلَيْهِ وَلا كَفَّارَة
> > حسنه الألباني في صحيح ابن خزيمة   -
>
> [صحيح ابن خزيمة -  كتاب الصوم](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&)
>
> Ibn Khuzaymah (1999) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever breaks his fast in Ramadaan **by mistake** does not have to make up that day or offer expiation.” *Classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh Ibn Khuzaymah.*

If I am not misunderstanding, the most accurate translation of that word should instead be "forgetfully". If I am not wrong, this is also the majority view. See what is mentioned in [this article](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/08/09/the-complete-guide-to-fasting/):

> ... **accidentally performing an act that vitiates the fast**. It also includes acts performed by force of a third party. **Accidentally means** that one remembers that one is fasting but broke the fast by one’s own doing without the intention to purposely break the fast.
>
> [Tahtawi, Hashiyya al-Tahtawi; Related in Radd al-Muhtar]

So either it seems to be a bad translation in islamQA or that they do not follow the view mentioned above, therefore my question:

### Which scholars say that your fast is valid even if you eat or drink by mistake under Ramadan?

Adding a list of scholars who consider the fast *invalid* would be a bonus.

---

**Side note:** by "eat and drink" I mean anything that normally breaks the fast. By "mistake", I do not mean *forgetfully*. My definition of mistake is as quoted in the content above, i.e:

> *Accidentally means that one remembers that one is fasting but broke the fast by one’s own doing without the intention to purposely break the fast.*

*In the Maliki fiqh, it is mentioned [here](http://www.archive.org/download/ibnacher/ibnacher.pdf) that they do say that your fast is valid if for instance a fly somehow gets in to your throat. They say this because you had no chance of avoiding this, i.e it wasn't your mistake.*

Therefore similar situations are not included in my definition of "mistake".

---

*One example of mistake would be like if you brush your teeth, and accidentally swallows water or something.The famous salafi scholar Ibn Baz would for instance say that the fast is still valid in [this case](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/108014). Majmoo’ Fataawa al-Shaykh Ibn Baaz (15/260).*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62107/discussion-on-question-by-kilise-which-scholars-say-that-your-fast-is-valid-even).

Answer (score 1):

### Shia View

Regarding the issue of eating or drinking by mistake, (if I mistake not), the view of all Shia scholars (Marja' al-taqlid) is that it (if is done inadvertently) doesn't invalidate the fast, according to Shia scholars such as:

- Ayatollah Khamenei
- Ayatollah Sistani
- Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi.

And so forth.

Hopefully, it helps you (to some extent!).

---

**Source:**

- [http://hadana.ir](http://hadana.ir/%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%87%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C-%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C/)
- [www.sistani.org](https://www.sistani.org/persian/book/25103/4035/)

Comment: Great! I am mostly looking for the sunni view but this information is of course also good. God bless you! off-topic: Does any Shia state that fast is broken if you eat accidentally?